# Where to put auth information

Tags: ruby, authentication, user-interface, twitter, rubygems

So I'm making a small program in VisualRuby that can tweet. So here's what my `main.rb` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'vrlib'
require 'twitter_oauth'

#make program output in real time so errors visible in VR.
STDOUT.sync = true
STDERR.sync = true

#everything in these directories will be included
my_path = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require_all Dir.glob(my_path + "/bin/**/*.rb") 

LoginWindow.new.show
```

and my `LoginWindow.rb` looks like this

```
require 'twitter_oauth'

class LoginWindow #(change name)

    include GladeGUI

    client = TwitterOAuth::Client.new(
        :consumer_key => '****',
        :consumer_secret => '****',
        :token => '****-****',
        :secret => '****'
    )

    def show()
        load_glade(__FILE__)  #loads file, glade/MyClass.glade into @builder
        set_glade_all() #populates glade controls with insance variables (i.e. Myclass.label1) 
        show_window() 
    end 

    def button1__clicked(*argv)
        if client.authorized? 
            puts "true"
        end
    end

end
```

And finally my window looks like this:
[image]

Now when I run this and click the login button, VR spits this out

```
C:/Users/*/visualruby/Test/bin/LoginWindow.rb:22:in `button1__clicked': undefined local variable or method `client' for #<LoginWindow:0x3f56aa8>
     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vrlib-0.0.33/lib/GladeGUI.rb:146:in `call'
     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vrlib-0.0.33/lib/GladeGUI.rb:146:in `block (3 levels) in parse_signals'
     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vrlib-0.0.33/lib/GladeGUI.rb:331:in `call'
     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vrlib-0.0.33/lib/GladeGUI.rb:331:in `main'
     from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vrlib-0.0.33/lib/GladeGUI.rb:331:in `show_window'
     from C:/Users/*/visualruby/Test/bin/LoginWindow.rb:17:in `show'
     from main.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

I don't think I'm supposed to put the `client = Twitter....` stuff inside the `LoginWindow` class but I can't think of anywhere else to put it. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: maybe you should transform client in a instance variable. You could call TwitterOAuth inside a initialize method.

Comment: @amalrikmaia what exactly do you mean? are you saying to have an initialize function with an instance variable `@client` inside of it?

Comment: _are you saying to have an initialize function with an instance variable @client inside of it?_  Yes.

Comment: @amalrikmaia this worked, such a simple solution don't know why I didn't think of it. Please post this as the answer and I'll approve it, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick solution for what you need.
in your LoginWindow.rb

```
def initialize
   @client = TwitterOAuth::Client.new( 
       :consumer_key => '****',
       :consumer_secret => '****',
       :token => '****-****',
       :secret => '****'
   )
end


def button1__clicked(*argv)
    if @client.authorized? 
        puts "true"
    end
end
```

The problem with this solution is now you can't call button1_clicked without initializing LogginWindow before, so be careful.